# Inheritance of VisualStateGroup / VisualState in a XAML Style / base class

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, expression-blend, visualstatemanager

- I have a base class `SecurePage` which inherit from `UserControl`.
- Every 'page' inside of the app inherit from `SecurePage`.
- I want to define in the default `Style` of `SecurePage` a `VisualStateGroup` with some `VisualState`s.

**The problem is, that in the derived classes are none of these `VisualState`s available.**

`var states = VisualStateManager.GetVisualStateGroups(this);`

Returns an empty list.

If I copy my `XAML` `VisualState` definition and paste it into my `DerivadedFooSecurePage`, I can easily go to the state:

```
VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Blink", false);
```

---

Same problem as described here: [VisualState in abstract control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18921294/visualstate-in-abstract-control)

---

#### Some more Details

**SecurePage**

```
[TemplateVisualState(GroupName = "State", Name = "Normal")]
[TemplateVisualState(GroupName = "State", Name = "Blink")]
public class SecurePage: UserControl
{
    public SecurePage()
    {
        DefaultStyleKey = typeof(HtSecurePage);
    }
}
```

---

```
<Style TargetType="basic:SecurePage">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="basic:SecurePage">
                <Grid>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="Signals">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Blink">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="border">
                                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="#FF3AFF00">
                                            <EasingColorKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                                <BounceEase EasingMode="EaseIn" Bounciness="3" Bounces="4"/>
                                            </EasingColorKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                        </EasingColorKeyFrame>
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                    <Border 
                        x:Name="border"
                        BorderThickness="5"
                        BorderBrush="Transparent"
                        IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**InfoPage**

Info.xaml.cs

```
namespace Views.General
{
    public partial class Info
    {
        public Info()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Info.xaml

```
<basic:SecurePage
    x:Class="Views.General.Info"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    xmlns:basic="clr-namespace:Foo.PlcFramework.Controls.Basic;assembly=Foo"
    FontSize="14">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="HelloWorld"/>
    </Grid>
</basic:SecurePage>
```

## Live Debugging

[image]

- `states = 0`
- Nothing happens after calling `VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Blink", false);`

[image]

- `states = 0`
- Nothing happens after calling `VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Blink", false);`

## Copy the VisualState into the derivaded class

```
namespace Views.General
{
    [TemplateVisualState(GroupName = "State", Name = "Normal")]
    [TemplateVisualState(GroupName = "State", Name = "Blink")]
    public partial class Info
    {
        public Info()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var states = VisualStateManager.GetVisualStateGroups(this);
            VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Blink", false);
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
<basic:SecurePage 
    x:Class="Views.General.Info"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    xmlns:basic="clr-namespace:Foo.PlcFramework.Controls.Basic;assembly=Foo"
    FontSize="14">
    <Grid>
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="Signals">
                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                <VisualState x:Name="Blink">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="border">
                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="#FF3AFF00">
                                <EasingColorKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                    <BounceEase EasingMode="EaseIn" Bounciness="3" Bounces="4"/>
                                </EasingColorKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                            </EasingColorKeyFrame>
                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <TextBlock Text="HelloWorld"/>
        <Border 
            x:Name="border"
            BorderThickness="5"
            BorderBrush="Transparent"
            IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
    </Grid>
</basic:SecurePage >
```

[image]

- `states = 0`
- **After calling `VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Blink", false);` the state is changed!!**

**I just want to define the state in the `XAML Style` definition of `SecurePage` and go to the state in any derivaded class!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Diagnosis

After some poking around I've finally found the culprit - it's the `UserControl` itself. More precisely - [overridden `StateGroupsRoot` property](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/UserControl.cs,63), which is used by the `VisualStateManager.GoToState` method. Normally, it returns the root element of the control's template, but in case of `UserControl` it returns the value of `UserControl.Content` property. So what happens is that when you call `GoToState`, states defined in your template are not taken into account.

### Solution

There are at least two solutions to this problem.

**First solution** is to derive your base class (`SecurePage`) from `ContentControl` instead of `UserControl`. The latter isn't that much different - it defaults `Focusable` and `IsTabStop` properties to `false`, and `HorizontanContentAlignment` and `VerticalContentAlignment` to `Stretch`. Also, apart from overriding mentioned `StateGroupsRoot` property, it provides its own `AutomationPeer` (a [`UserControlAutomationPeer`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Automation/Peers/UserControlAutomationPeer.cs)), but I don't think you need to worry about that.

**The second solution** is to use `VisualStateManager.GoToElementState` on the template root instead. For example:

```
public class SecurePage : UserControl
{
    //Your code here...

    private FrameworkElement TemplateRoot { get; set; }

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        if (Template != null)
            TemplateRoot = GetVisualChild(0) as FrameworkElement;
        else
            TemplateRoot = null;
    }

    public bool GoToVisualState(string name, bool useTransitions)
    {
        if (TemplateRoot is null)
            return false;
        return VisualStateManager.GoToElementState(TemplateRoot, name, useTransitions);
    }
}
```

### Other considerations

Calling `VisualStateManager.GetVisualStateGroups` on your control yields an empty list because it's just an ordinary attached dependency property accessor, and you didn't set<sup>1</sup> that property on your control. To get hold of the groups you've defined in the template, you should call it passing the template root as argument. By the same principle, you don't expect `Grid.GetColumn` called on your control to return a value you set somewhere in your template.

Regarding calling `GoToState` in your control's constructor - it's most likely not going to work, since your control is only **being instantiated**, and most likely its `Templtate` is null (and remember you define visual states inside the template). It's better to move that logic to `OnApplyTemplate` override.

---

<sup>1</sup> Since `VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroupsProperty` is read-only, by *set* I mean add items to the list returned by `VisualStateManager.GetVisualStateGroups`

Comment: Thanks for your explanation!

Answer (score 0):

I tired to regenerate the scenario you mentioned in question and I am able to get the list of `VisualStateGroup`from base class. Here is sample which I implemented.

First, you need to get `VisualStateGroup` of current base class and then add custom created group to it.

**Base Class**

```
public partial class SecurePage : UserControl
{
    public VisualStateGroup vsGroup = new VisualStateGroup();

    public SecurePage()
    {
        System.Collections.IList groups = VisualStateManager.GetVisualStateGroups(this);


        VisualState state1 = new VisualState() { Name = "State1" };

        Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
        DoubleAnimation anim = new DoubleAnimation(1, 0, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0));
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(anim, new PropertyPath(FrameworkElement.OpacityProperty));
        sb.AutoReverse = true;
        sb.Children.Add(anim);

        state1.Storyboard = sb;

        vsGroup.States.Add(state1);

        groups.Add(vsGroup);
    }
}
```

**Derived Class**

Root of derived class is type of Base class. Keep in mind to change that without fail. First line of XAML file. Check below.

```
<UserControl x:Class="WPFTest.SecurePage"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFTest"
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

    <Grid>
        <Rectangle x:Name="rect" Height="100" Width="100" Fill="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>

public partial class DerivadedFooSecurePage : SecurePage
{
    public DerivadedFooSecurePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var states = VisualStateManager.GetVisualStateGroups(this);

        //VisualStateManager.GoToElementState(this.rect, "State1", false);
    }
}
```

Further can implement `DerivadedFooSecurePage`  on any window or other usercontrol.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! *I want to define VisualStates in a base class and use it in the derivaded classes. Define it in the Code behind is no solution!* I have added more details to understand my problem

Answer (score 0):

## Workaround solution

I defined an `enum` with a value for every available `VisualState`.

```
public enum ESecurePageVisualState
{
    Normal,
    Blink
}
```

Added a `DependencyProperty` in the `SecurePage` class.

```
/// <summary>
/// Set the visual State of the page
/// </summary>
public ESecurePageVisualState VisualState
{
    get => (ESecurePageVisualState)GetValue(VisualStateProperty);
    set => SetValue(VisualStateProperty, value);
}

/// <summary>
/// The <see cref="VisualState"/> DependencyProperty.
/// </summary>
public static readonly DependencyProperty VisualStateProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("VisualState", typeof(ESecurePageVisualState), typeof(SecurePage), new PropertyMetadata(ESecurePageVisualState.Normal));
```

And changed the `Style` of the `SecurePage`:

```
<Style TargetType="basic:SecurePage">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="basic:SecurePage">
                <Grid x:Name="Grid">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="Signals">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Blink">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="border">
                                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="#FF3AFF00">
                                            <EasingColorKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                                <BounceEase EasingMode="EaseIn" Bounciness="3" Bounces="4"/>
                                            </EasingColorKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                        </EasingColorKeyFrame>
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                    <Border 
                        x:Name="border"
                        BorderThickness="5"
                        BorderBrush="Transparent"
                        IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>                            
                        <ei:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=basic:SecurePage}, Path=VisualState}" Value="{x:Static basic:ESecurePageVisualState.Normal}">
                            <ei:GoToStateAction StateName="Normal" TargetName="Grid" TargetObject="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Grid}}"/>
                        </ei:DataTrigger>
                        <ei:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=basic:SecurePage}, Path=VisualState}" Value="{x:Static basic:ESecurePageVisualState.Blink}">
                            <ei:GoToStateAction StateName="Blink" TargetName="Grid" TargetObject="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Grid}}"/>
                        </ei:DataTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Now I'm able to Change the `VisualState` via a property.

```
public partial class Info
{
    public Info()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += (sender, args) =>
        {
            VisualState = ESecurePageVisualState.Blink;
        };
    }       
}
```

---

If you find a better solution, let me know!